# XAMPP Apache Won't Start (I have changed the ports)

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp

I looked around for the same question, but the fix doesn't work for me. I am trying to run my Apache Server on Xampp, but I get this:

```
Problem detected!
23:01:34  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 5792!
23:01:34  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
23:01:34  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
23:01:34  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
23:01:34  [Apache]  Problem detected!
23:01:34  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 5792!
23:01:34  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
23:01:34  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
23:01:34  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I don't have Skype on, and even if I had, I have changed the ports for Apache (i used 8080 and 4433). I have watched youtube videos and searched on forums, but I couldn't fix my problem. 
If anyone knows how to fix it, I will love you till the end of time. Thanks!

(I might add that, I already tried to install apache, not from Xampp, but I deleted it, because I thought that it might listen on those ports. Still, nothing...)

*EDIT 
I have closed some features that I previously enabled, because earlier I have tried to use IIS for the same puropose. Now that I have closed these features, I don't get the error as before. As a matter of fact, I don't get any errors anymore, but if I try to start Apache, it just says "Attempting to start Apache service..." and stays like this.

PS I use Windows 7

Comment: Use the program from microsoft called process explorer,find out what is the process with the number 5792 and close it

Comment: Depends on your environment but on Linux you run `sudo netstat -tulpn` and it will list ip:port and process name.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I changed my port to 8088, because it seems that Tomcat (that is another feature of XAMPP) uses 8080. Apache started now.